# McLaurin Polynomial for $e^{3x^{2}}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function

**The Problem**

My calculus book featured a few examples where Taylor Polynomials could be constructed from known McLaurin Polynomials. I wanted to try doing it on my own, so I made up my own problem, which was to find the first order Taylor Polynomial of $f$ where $f(x) = e^{3x^{2}}$ around $x = 1$.

First I calculated the answer (which I've double-checked already, and which is correct), using the standard method:

$$P_1(x) = f(1) + f'(1)(x-1)$$
$$P_1(x) = e^{3\times 1^{2}} + e^{3\times 1^{2}}6\times 1(x-1)$$
$$P_1(x) = e^3(1 + 6(x-1))$$

Then I tried getting the same result, using the methods developed in the book. However, as it seems, this gives a different result.

**The Method**

$$e^{3x^{2}} = e^{(3x^{2}-3)+3} = e^{3x^{2} -3}e^{3}$$

Now let $t = 3x^2 - 3$, which gives:

$$e^{3x^{2}} = e^3 e^t$$

$x = 1 \implies t=0$, so I tried replacing $e^t$ with its expansion around $x = 0$:

$$e^t = 1 + t +O(t^2)$$

If that's true, then:

$$P_1(x)=e^3(1 + t) = e^3(1 + 3(x^2 - 1))$$

Obviously, this cannot be true, since it contains an $x^2$-term, so I do see that it doesn't make sense. However, I want to ask a few questions.

**My Questions**

I'll list them, for simplicity:

1. Which part of the solution leads to the incorrect result? I'm guessing that it has to do with the fact that $t = 0$ doesn't imply that $x = 1$, since $x = -1$ also gives $t = 0$. Although I'm not sure.
2. Can I solve the problem correctly, using known McLaurin Polynomials? If so, how do I do that?
3. As an expansion of question 1: What exactly does what I calculated mean? Or does it even mean anything? Now when I think about it, I guess that (using the same arguments as in my solution) the polynomial $e^3(1 + 3(x^2 - 1))$ could be a "first order Taylor Polynomial" around $x = -1$ as well, which is really strange. Can I somehow understand what the heck I've done? Is there any meaning behind my result, whatsoever? Even if it's not important to the question, I'm curious about this, having sat down with it for a while now. (I could care less about the question itself, since I made it up...)
4. Maybe a redundant question since it's related to 3, but why do I get an $x^2$-term?

Lastly, I'm very tired, so if this is the result of me being uncareful somewhere with the maths, I am sorry about that. I've checked it several times to make sure that's not the case, but you never know what you're missing late in the evening.

Comment: You took the expansion at a different point.

Comment: For question $2$, you could easily see that $$e^x=1+x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3+\dots$$ $$e^{3x^2}=1+(3x^2)+\frac12(3x^2)^2+\frac16(3x^2)^3+\dots$$

Comment: +Simple Art That could make sense! At which point did I take the expansion, which isn't $x=1$?

Comment: +Simple Art I response to your response to question 2: Wouldn't that be expanded around $x = 0$?

Comment: Yeah, if you did the expansion at $x=0$, you would've gotten $P_1(x)=1+0x$, and maybe your supposed to go up one more term if it ends up like this?

Comment: I meant that you could use the expansion of $e^x$ at any point and just plug $3x^2$ into the thing.

Comment: P.S. graphing is always a good way to check your expansions

Comment: +Simple Art I just graphed it, and it seems like what I did gives me a parabola that intersects $f$ at both $x = 1$ and $x = -1$. It almost seems like an approximation at both $x = 1$ and $x = -1$. Also, I'll try to understand how expanding it at $x = 0$ can get you the Polynomial at $x = 1$. Maybe it's just that I'm tired now, but I can't quite see the connection yet.

Comment: +Simple Art Wow, I forgot to add that the problem was to find the Taylor Polynomial around $x = 1$. Now I understand what you said and why! I'm sorry about this. I edited the question.

Comment: @Max You had to put $t=x-1$.

Comment: ;) Always love to be of assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us put $t=x-1$

or

$x=t+1$,

thus
$e^{3x^2}=e^{3t^2+6t+3}$

$=e^3e^{3t^2+6t}$

$=e^3.(1+3t^2+6t+O(t^2))$

$=e^3.(1+6t+O(t^2))$

$=e^3(1+6(x-1))+O((x-1)^2).$

so no error.

Comment: This is a great answer to question number 2! Thanks a lot! Although I'm still a bit curious about question 3 (I think I know about question 1 already, based on this answer).  Do you possibly see what my solution produced?

Comment: Arround $-1$, you will put $t=x+1$.

Comment: +Abdallah Hammam I understand, but what in particular does my method produce? Is there a meaning to my (seemingly wrong) result, having put $t = 3x^2 - 3$?

Comment: If you put $t=3x^2-3$, there will be a problem with the rest . $O(t^2)$ will be $O(9(x^2-1)^2)$ .

Comment: +Abdallah Hammam I'll accept your answer, since it is relevant. I understand what you mean, and that explains the $x^2$-term I got later on as well. So I'm guessing that you should make substitutions $t = \phi(x)$, where $\phi$ is a first degree polynomial, in order to avoid these problems? In that case, I understand most of it :) Thinking about what the $t$ I had does geometrically and stuff still confuses me a bit though, to be honest. I really don't get the weird graph I got when I plotted $y = 3x^2 - 3$. Maybe it's not meaningful, though.

Comment: Maybe it's more correct to say $\phi(x) = 0$ has one root, rather than "$\phi$ is a first degree polynomial", so that $t = 0 \implies x = 0$.

Comment: All the difference comes from the remaider term $O(?)$.